# Can I draw a line on a map with altitude?

Tags: uwp

I want to map the flight of a drone on the MapControl in a UWP app. I tried to set the altitude for every point in a path, but the line is still drawn on the ground. Is there a way to have an elevated line on the map?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. Please review how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Polyline` doesn't support altitude at the moment. What you can do is add a `MapIcon` (or XAML element) on every node of the path at the altitude you want. That way you have a line on the ground pinpointing the exact location there AND a pin in the sky showing the height.

Comment: Can you definitely position a XAML element at an altitude? I can make this work with a MapIcon but my bound XAML elements always appear at an altitude of 0.

Comment: Yes you can, my mistake. Unless the mapstyle is set to a 3D map it won't show points with altitude. Makes sense.